how to add trial to existing subscription on Google play console?
I can't find option to add trial.
how to add trial to existing subscription on Google play console?
Is there any other way but to create a new subscription?
I want add trial to existing subscrition.
If anyone knows how, please help.

Have you seen this?

@tomerpacific Thank you for your comment. but I didn't find the information I wanted.
